# How can I send a control to front of another controls?

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, uicontrolview

I want to change the z-index of a control, but I did not find what I was looking for, even the translationz and elevation attributes did not have any effect in order to put one control on another control. 
What approach do you recommend?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_direction1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_search_box"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cancel_direction_visibale_search_Layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_directiontop_layout">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cancel_box_direction_Img"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size40dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel3"
                android:tint="#6e6c6c" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close_box_direction_Img"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size25dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size8dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/open_menu_change_direction_layout"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sports_car"
                android:tint="#5e5d5d" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/open_menu_change_direction_layout"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size40dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_ic_menu_image"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font16sp"
                android:tint="#4e4c4c" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/select_origin_item_Img"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size30dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/size2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel3"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font16sp"
                android:tint="#535252" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location_name_direction"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext_search_box"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/size5dp"
                android:textColor="#060606"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font16sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/location_name_direction_Edit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext_search_box"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/size5dp"
                android:textColor="#060606"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font16sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/area_name_direction_A_Txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size2dp"
                android:textColor="#c14b4a4b"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size25dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size3dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_ff"
                android:textColor="#605e5e"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Relative_layout"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size290dp"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size10dp"
                android:background="#d0838181" />
```

i want to send recycler to front of parent relative layout (set absoulte postion to recycler).

I also used the spinner, but since I can not catch clicking event outside of the spinner, I need to use recycler.

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/searchbox_recycler_view2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Relative_layout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_row_item_tool_box"
                android:translationZ="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size20dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size4dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Relative_layout"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/size2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_increase_size_option" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/select_dest_item_Img"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size30dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size5dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/size2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel3"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font16sp"
                android:tint="#535252" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/area_name_direction"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext_search_box"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/size5dp"
                android:textColor="#060606"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font16sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/area_name_direction_B_Txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size2dp"
                android:textColor="#c14b4a4b"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size25dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size3dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bb"
                android:textColor="#605e5e"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_destination"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size320dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size2dp"
                app:ms_enableErrorLabel="false"
                app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="false"
                app:ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
                app:ms_multiline="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_directionbottom_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/drawing_direction"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size30dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_double_arrow_right"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size15dp"
                android:tint="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i guess you are looking for  framelayout.

Comment: Please provide your layout xml file.

Comment: @SagarChavadaI, I found some sample code of frame-layout but those not working, can do you helping me with a Practical example.